# Plug in hard drive without mounting

Tags: macos

Is it possible to plug in a hard drive without mounting it?

I will be immediately running `ddrescue` after plugging it in.

Also, how will I learn the new device ID? (When it automounts, I had used the `mount` command to learn the device ID.)

Comment: Is it possible: Hell yes. I tis possible with OSX? No idea. If you need to rescue data plug it into a simple Linux distribution or a BSD distribution. One of the bare bones ones, not something desktop oriented or with a GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.  "Disk Arbitrator is a Mac OS X forensic utility designed to help the user ensure correct forensic procedures are followed during imaging of a disk device. Disk Arbitrator is essentially a user interface to the Disk Arbitration framework, which enables a program to participate in the management of block storage devices, including the automatic mounting of file systems. When enabled, Disk Arbitrator will block the mounting of file systems to avoid mounting as read-write and violating the integrity of the evidence."

- https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator